# Is it possible to insert an incomplete jsx snippet into a render function of another jsx file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have file `Incomplete.jsx` and `Main.jsx`

`Incomplete.jsx` looks as follows:

```
<Hey text="Hello World!" />
<Hey text="You made it to the end of the world!" />
```

`Main.jsx` looks as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import playlist from './Incomplete';

class Hey extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() { 
    const {text} = this.props;

    return (
      <p>{text}</p>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{playlist}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then how can I make the program in such a way, that React will render

```
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Hey text="Hello World!" />
        <Hey text="You made it to the end of the world!" />
      </div>
    ); 
  }
```

Instead of

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>{playlist}</div>
    );
  }
```

by importing `Incomplete.jsx`?

Because right now the code doesn't work.

And is something like this even possible? I know that if I create `Incomplete.jsx`, then I will get a lot of errors. I see components as functions, so the idea is that `Incomplete.jsx` is a file with all the 'function calls' and the definition will be in `Main.jsx`.

One constraint that I have is that I don't want to do any imports in `Incomplete.jsx`.

It's for a project that teaches children how to use some simple pre-defined React Components by simply calling them in the `Incomplete.jsx` file.

Comment: It's possible if `Incomplete.jsx` will export an array of elements. I wouldn't consider it a good practice though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `incomplete.jsx` should look something like this:

```
const Playlist = (props) => {
   return (
      <div>
        <Hey text="Hello World!" />
        <Hey text="You made it to the end of the world!" />
      </div>
   )
}

export default Playlist;
```

If you have your import in your `main.jsx` like this: 
`import Playlist from './Incomplete';`
You can call your code by using `<Playlist />` in the `render()`.

Because your `incomplete` returns a component, and because we call it like that, you could add properties to it. E.g. `<Playlist amountOfNumbers={1} />`. Which you can retrieve from the `props` field in your `Playlist`

If the component you'd like to render inside your `main.jsx` is supposed to have it's own `state`. You can rewrite your `Playlist` to something like this:

```
export default class Playlist extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Hey text="Hello World!" />
         <Hey text="You made it to the end of the world!" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The stateless (first) example, can be done without `imports`.